# Paragraph reversal using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a paragraph like this:

```
Rohit is a good boy.
He loves poetry.
He also sings.
```

I want to reverse the paragraph like this:

```
.boy good a is Rohit
.poetry loves He
.sings also He
```

I have this working script from [this site](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/94180-how-to-reverse-a-string-help/).

```
Loop, Parse, clipboard, %A_Space%
    new :=  RegExReplace(A_LoopField,"(.*)(\p{P})$","$2$1") A_Space new


Msgbox %    Trim(new,A_Space)
```

But it can only reverse one line at a time. I am not able to modify the script for my purpose.

Comment: That's an algorithmically solvable question which has lots of examples on the internet and I don't see any attempt to solve it in your post. Stack Overflow helps you solve the problems with your code, not to provide complete solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the lines and create an array containing all the words of the current line, then loop through the words backwards. And if a word ends with a punctuation char, put it in the beginning of the word.

```
text = 
(
Rohit is a good boy.
He loves poetry.
He also sings.
)

punctuationCharArray := [".",",","-",":",";","!","?"]
reversedText := ""
Loop, parse, text, `n, `r
{
    line := A_LoopField
    wordArray := StrSplit(line, " ")
    i := wordArray.MaxIndex()
    While (i>0) {
        rawWord := wordArray[i]
        punctuationChar := ""
        Loop % punctuationCharArray.MaxIndex() { ;check if the last character of the word is one of the specified punctuation chars
            If (SubStr(rawWord, -0) = punctuationCharArray[A_Index]) {
                punctuationChar := punctuationCharArray[A_Index]
                Break
            }
        }
        word := (punctuationChar ? SubStr(rawWord, 1, -1) : rawWord) ;if there is a punctuation char in the end, omit that
        reversedText .= punctuationChar . word . " " ;add the current (punctuation char), word and a space to the output text variable.
        i--
    }
    reversedText .= "`r`n" ;add a new line
}
MsgBox % reversedText
```

Output:

> .boy good a is Rohit
>   .poetry loves He
>   .sings also He

The next step would be to reverse brackets too.